# ERROR Source option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, unsupported-class-version

#### It all happens when I was trying to build a springboot application by `./mvnw clean install`

When I first run the install command, it runs into following problem.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.749s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 21 02:14:32 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project spring-social-twitter4j: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerException**
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/SS%20Computer/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/SS%20Computer/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

I searched the problem on Stackoverflow and was able to solve this problem by the post

[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223536/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin2-3-2comp)

Then, I got into another problem

```
[ERROR] Source option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

I'm on OS X. `mvn -v` shows:

```
Maven home: /Users/matthuntington/Desktop/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Here is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.packtpub.restapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticket-management</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ticket-management</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>                
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 1.5 on java9 that basically is an unsupported combination. You are also trying to use Spring Boot 1.5 with Spring 5, whereas it is designed to work with Spring 4.3.

Comment: @M. Deinum. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can specify maven source/target version by adding these properties to your pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: In my case, it was not spring boot and there was no 1.5 specification in the pom.xml, probably 1.5 is the default. I added <properties> as a child of <project>, and it worked.

Answer (score 69):

I think this means that

- You are using JDK9 or later
- Your project uses **maven-compiler-plugin** with an old version which defaults to Java 5.

You have three options to solve this

1. Downgrade to **JDK7** or **JDK8** (meh)
2. Use **maven-compiler-plugin** version or later, because

   > **NOTE:** Since 3.8.0 the default value has changed from 1.5 to 1.6
   >   See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0</version>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Indicate to the **maven-compiler-plugin** to use source level 6 and target 6 (or later).

   **Best practice** recommended by https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

   > Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.6 and the default target setting is 1.6, independently of the JDK you run Maven with.
   >   You are highly encouraged to change these defaults by setting source and target as described in [Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

   or use

   ```
   <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   ```

Answer (score 16):

This error might be also for plugin versions. You can fix it in the *.POM* file like the followings:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have following configuration in your `pom.xml` file.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to set the version of the maven compiler plugin to 3.8.0 and specify the release (9 for in your case, 11 in mine)

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me!!!!**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>academy.learnprogramming</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>10</target>
                <source>10</source>
                <release>10</release>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

## In IntelliJ:

1. Open `Project Structure` (**⌘;**) > `Modules` > `YOUR MODULE` -> **Language
   level:** set 9, in your case.
2. Repeat for each module.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There can be corrupted jar file for which it may show error as "ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)"
You need to delete all jar files for which it shows the error and add this Dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error: "Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later"
after I changed the pom.xml

```
<java.version>7</java.version>
```

to

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
```

Later to realise the property was used with a dash insteal of a dot:

```
  <source>${java-version}</source>
  <target>${java-version}</target>
```

(swearings), I replaced the dot with a dash and the error went away:

```
<java-version>11</javaversion>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set JDK 1.5 to your project and also all dependent project or jar file should also compiled with JDK 1.5